# Reading file from storage container with prefix "abc" and loading as json.. Errored as " 'BlobProperties' object has no attribute 'download_blob' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

Below is the code,

```
connection_string='DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=example;AccountKey='
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("example123")
files = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="ABC")
print(files)
for blob in files:
     print("\t" + blob.name)
     blobr = blob.download_blob().readall()
     print(blobr)
     tmp_data = blobr.read().decode('utf-8')
     print(tmp.data)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'BlobProperties' object has no attribute 'download_blob'
```

Please guide on how to read the blob from storage container and load json or do further processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `list_blobs` method only returns blob properties, not the blob object. So you cannot call `download_blob` method via blob property.

You should change your code like below in the `for` statement:

```
for blob in files:
    blob_client=blob_service_client.get_blob_client("like example123, this is your container name",blob.name)
    blobr = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the help!!